# Missing required parameter for route Laravel 10

Tags: laravel, forms

I have a function called update in my controller which gets a certain project with a certain id. Then I have a form in my blade file with an action atribute that sends them to the edit function in my controller. It is defined in the update function when I hover over the variables but in the form the value is null. The right ID does display in the url

I've looked at it with a classmate of mine and she has the same code but not the same issue.

Here is the code:

The update function

```
 $project = project::find($id);
        return view('update', compact('project'));
```

The form in the blade file:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('ProjectsController.edit'), $project->id }}" autocomplete="on">
```

What am I doing wrong here? Or could the issue lie elsewhere? Laravel gives an error at the line the form is in. I tried using just $project or $id but neither work. I also tried to put it like this:

```
action="{{ route('ProjectsController.edit', $project->id)
```

Also tried just $project and $id here but this didn't work either. I am using laravel 10.

Comment: okay so I fixed it. Here is the fix:

action="{{ route('ProjectsController.edit',['id' => $project->id ])}}

Answer (score 0):

So I was trying to get the id out of the variable project but project was an array. The `$project->id` needed to be in a variable to be able to be passed to the function.

This is what it looks like in sytrax:

```
action="{{ route('ProjectsController.edit',['id' => $project->id ]) }}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/urls#urls-for-named-routes    ... always read the documentation first

Comment: If you use Route Model Binding its not necessary to use an array nor to use the id directly, you can just pass the $project variable and laravel will get the data by itself.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-model-binding